# Creating a numpy array with optional padding

Tags: python, numpy

The task is relatively simple: read a file, for each entry get records, for each record check the year from a dict and create a temporal profile. I would like to do this as efficiently as possible since the file (and the dict) is pretty large.

The code I have is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
with open('entries.tsv', 'r') as entries:
    offset = 1920
    size = 100
    for line in islice(entries, None):
        prot, recs = line.strip().split('\t')
        ids = recs.split(" ")
        years = Counter([id_dict[id] for id in ids])
        print(np.array(sorted(list(years.items()))))
        input()
```

The issue here is that you can get an output where certain years are skipped since there is no record that correspond to that year (1995 in this case):

```
[[1992    3]
 [1993    3]
 [1994    2]
 [1996    2]
 [1997    2]
 [1998    5]
 [1999   11]
 [2000    3]
 [2001    4]
 [2002    3]
 [2003    3]
 [2004    2]
 [2005    3]
 [2006    3]
 [2007    3]
 [2008    1]
 [2009    2]
 [2010    2]
 [2011    3]
 [2012   10]
 [2013    4]
 [2014    4]
 [2015    5]
 [2016    2]
 [2017    5]
 [2018    4]
 [2019    1]]
```

Since I will merge all these into a single large numpy array I would like them all to be the same size, for example the last 100 years. I don't actually need the years but having them there makes it easier to spot this type of issue.

I dont know the exact number of entries in the file, so I can't generate the array in advance. I am thinking there should be a smarter way than creating an array of the desired size, and looping over the counter to increment the specific indices.

Comment: So what you want is for example `[1995 0]` inserted, because there is no record?